# Как сделать правильно через указатель на указатель?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, вектор

Нужно создать 2 матрицы размером m,n и вектор B. Как сделать правильно через указатель?

```
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Enter m ");
    scanf("%f", m);

    printf("Enter n ");
    scanf("%f", n);

    int *B = new int B[m];
    int **A = new int  *(*(A + m) + n);
    int **C = new int  *(*(C + m) + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = new int[i][j];
        C[i][j] = new int[i][j];
    }

}
```

Comment: ну для начала что вы хотите сделать `*(*(A + m) + n)` тут? Потом `A[i][j] = new int` тут точно не так. Вообще писали бы вы `int ** A = (int *)[n]; A[0] = new int[m]` как-то так...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы имеете в виду следующее

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    size_t m;

    std::cout << "Enter m: ";
    std::cin >> m;

    size_t n;

    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    int *B = new int [m];

    int **A = new int * [m];
    int **C = new int * [m];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        A[i] = new int [n];
        C[i] = new int [n];
    }


    //  some processing of A, B, and C

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        delete [] A[i];
        delete [] C[i];
    }

    delete [] C;
    delete [] A;
    delete [] B;

    return 0;
}
```

То есть вы хотите динамически распределить одномерный массив, адресуемый указателем `B` типа `int *`, и массивы массивов, адресуемых указателями `A` и `C`, имеющими тип `int **`.

Альтернативный подход - это вместо ручного распределения и освобождения памяти вы могли бы использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector`, объявленный в заголовке `<vector>`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    size_t m;

    std::cout << "Enter m: ";
    std::cin >> m;

    size_t n;

    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> B( m );
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A( m, std::vector<int>( n ) );
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> C( m, std::vector<int>( n ) );

    return 0;
}
```

С векторами вы можете работать как с массивами, используя оператор индексирования. Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    size_t m;

    std::cout << "Enter m: ";
    std::cin >> m;

    size_t n;

    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> B( m );
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A( m, std::vector<int>( n ) );
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> C( m, std::vector<int>( n ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < B.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        B[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? i / 2 : m - i / 2 - 1;
    }       

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )  A[i][j] = i * n + j;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < C.size(); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )  C[i][j] = m * n - 1 - i * n - j;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( int x : B ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for ( const auto &row : A )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &row : C )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Enter m: 10
Enter n: 10

 0  9  1  8  2  7  3  6  4  5 

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 

99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 
89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 
79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 
69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 
59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 
49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 
39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 
29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 
19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 
 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int * B = new int[m];
int ** A = new int*[m];
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    A[i] = new int[n];

....

for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    delete[] A[i];

delete[] A;
```

Примерно так...

Думаю, что преподаватель ждет от вас именно этого.